# File Upload Screen flow component is disabled on lightning page AKA - recordId is not passing to Screenflow

Tags: fileupload, lightning-page

I build a screen flow to upload a file to an oppty, using the fileUpload component
[image]

It works great when testing the flow itself, but when adding to a lighting page, the Upload file button is disabled

[image]

If I add a test data assignment as follow:
[image]

The upload file is enabled:
[image]

Note: the recordId is set as follow
[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have at least read access to the record, then the file upload component will be enabled. Looking at the fact that while hard coding the ID in test data, you are able to upload a file, it seems that when you are actually running the flow, your recordId is not being populated.

> Documentation:
>   **Related Record ID**  - Required. ID of the record to
>   associate the files with. If no value is passed, the component is
>   disabled.

It depends on where you have added the flow. If you are putting this flow on a record page and have enabled the `recordId` as an input variable, a checkbox "Pass record Id in to this variable" should appear below in the design configuration panel.

If you have done that as well, then it is likely an issue with one of the steps in the flow.

[image: Add recordId]

Comment: oops - Pass record Id in to this variable - Not checked on record page - Works